# Keycloak - WPF check permission

Tags: wpf, keycloak, openid

I have a WPF app (.net 462 & API .net5.0).

I have set the openid on the api and this work, the permission work, but on the WPF app i have to check the permission for app element (menu access, button access).

Getting the token work, but i don't know how to valid a scope when openid

Key clock config :

- Realm => demo-test
- Client => demo-test-client
- Client Role => DemoRole
- Authorization Scope => demo:read

  - Associated Permissions => Permission demo:read
  - Associated Policy  for role => DemoRole - Positive

I have create two user "user-test-ok" & "user-test-ko", "user-test-ok" have the client role "DemoRole".

I have test to user the introspection for validate the user have the scope "demo:read", but this not work.

I don't want use keycloak API, i want use the openid system for possibly change keycloak by other OAuth2.0 system.

This is my code to try to check the authorization scope :

```
var requestUri = new Uri($"https://localhost:8443/auth/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect");

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUri);
    req.Headers.Add("cache-control", "no-cache");
    req.Headers.Add("accept", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

    req.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "token_type_hint", "requesting_party_token" },
        { "token", tokenResult.AccessToken },
        { "client_id", clientId },
        { "client_secret", clientSecret },
        { "scope", "test:read" },
    });

    var response = client.SendAsync(req).Result;

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

}
```

Did you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

If I read the token introspection endpoint documentation [here](https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/authorization_services/topics/service/protection/token-introspection.html), then it says nothing about passing the scope ({ "scope", "test:read" },) as a parameter. Instead you take what you get back from that request and then you first check if the active claim is true. That signals that the token is still active and valid..

Then you just examine the data that is returned. Or you just use the scope value inside the access or ID-token to give the user access to the features in the application.

Do, check what the request returns in a tool like [Fiddler](https://getfiddler.com/).